# Speech Synthesis api not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech

I'm seeing an issue where speech synthesis in the below jsfiddle does not work (no spoken audio) in Chrome on MacOS (Chrome 113.0.5672.63, MacOS 13.2.1).

It's a bizarre issue because the speech synthesis does work in the same instance of Chrome in a web application I'm working on and also the jsfiddle works in Safari and Firefox on the same machine.

The first thing I'm curious about is if the jsfiddle code works for other folks in their Chrome instances. Knowing that will help me decide how much effort I want to invest in tracking down this problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/pilyugin/dgygqLw2/

```
var wordsToSpeak = [
  'Hello! This text should be longer than sixty or may be more symbols. Please see console log.',
  'Now end event is fired!',
  'You can use global variables to store utterance object.'
];
// this object for storing utterances globally
window.utterances = []; 

function speak(text) {
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
  utterance.lang = 'en-US';
  utterance.onend = function() {
    // this code is not called
    console.log(text);
  };

  // if you will comment this line, end event will not work!
  utterances.push(utterance);
  
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}

for (var i = 0; i < wordsToSpeak.length; i++) {
  speak(wordsToSpeak[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generally have a page auto-play audio in Chrome, and nope, that JSFiddle doesn't work out of the box on my Windows Chrome either.

Adding a button and wrapping the loop in

```
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < wordsToSpeak.length; i++) {
    speak(wordsToSpeak[i])
  }
});
```

makes it work after one clicks the button.

Comment: Ok, adding the button works for me too so it is tied to the autoplay permissions. The webapp I'm working on is run from localhost so it appears there Chrome is being more permissive about allowing autoplay.